# Fragments in a viewpager disappear only after 2 rotations

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've been running into a strange problem with fragments inside a viewpager. If I rotate the device once, everything seems to work and my fragments load with all their data intact. However on a second rotation, the fragments inside my viewpager seem to disappear. If i check isAdded(), it returns true, however isVisible() returns false. Is there a reason why a fragment would be added to my viewpager, but not visible?

Here's my Fragment which contains the viewpager:

```
public class DrawerFragment extends ParentFragment{

ViewPager viewPager;

GradingFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
ArrayList<ParentFragment> mGradingFragments;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    viewPager = (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    if(mFragments == null){
     mFragments = new ArrayList<ParentFragment>();
     mFragments.add(new FragmentA());
     mFragments.add(new FragmentB());
    }
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPager(getChildFragmentManager(), mFragments);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

Here's my PagerAdapter class

```
 public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<ParentFragment > fragments;

    public GradingFragmentPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<ParentFragment> fragments){
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public ParentFragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

}
```

What i don't understand is that it only seems to break on the second rotation. If i set a background color on the viewpager, after 2 rotations, the area where my fragments should be are the viewpagers background color. However if i look at it in debug mode, the fragment's are added to the pagerAdapter. They just not visible.

Also it doesn't seem like onCreateView is getting called on the 2 fragments inside the viewpager. I'm not entirely sure if that's expected behavior or not when using setRetainInstance(true). From what I understand, setting it on the parent fragment should handle it's child fragments as well. But don't the child fragment's views still need to be recreated each rotation?